# React Native: Cant find variable 'require' (at bundle)

Tags: react-native

I made a new react native project. Just react-native init myProject. I run react-native start to start the packager. I set up my phone and after i ran react-native run-android the app is installed in my phone.
When i launch the app it communicates with the packager but i have an error 
that cant't find variable require.
Any help?

[image]

Comment: line 15 'use strict';var _create=require('babel-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Your phone tries to connect to the debug server but it have not the address of your local server. You can try:

- Find you local ip address by executing ifconfig on Linux/Mac, for example: inet addr:192.168.0.3
- Shake the device to see menu options while app is running (if you don't have "Menu" button)
- Go to Dev Settings -> Debug server host & port for device in Debugging section and copy your local ip address with the specific port: 192.168.0.3:8081 (the port can be viewed when running npm start from the first tab) then go/press Back
- Shake the device to see menu options again and press Enable Live Reload (to see changes live when editing) or Reload

Shake the device to see menu options again and press Reload JS

Comment: I tried this. The only thing that changed is it can't find variable require (http:192.168.1.2:8081/index...)

Comment: Your phone is connected on the same network as your server? (Wifi)

Comment: you can try : `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and reload app

Comment: look this : [link](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#content) (end page)

Comment: Sorry, I have no more idea. You can re-check your ip and port of the server. Check server running. Check if your phone is connect in same network. Or you can build app in release [link](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.33/docs/signed-apk-android.html#generating-signed-apk), if run is your network bug.

Comment: Thank you for you time. I think that the problem is no in the communication with the server. The bundle seems to fetch

Comment: Yes the problem is not in the communication with server. I stopped the server and after i tried to open the app and ihave a could not connect to server problem. I started tha server and now i have the no variable 'require' problem